# Compacting str format variable arguments

Tags: python

I wanted to put every item in a very long dictionary in a single string that looks like a checker board, but the code comes out as very long and repetitive. Is there a way to make the format code (or the code itself) compact, while still using numbers as the item ID in the dictionary?

```
cell_dict = {}
for i in range(100):
    cell_dict.update({i+1:Cell(i)})

print('[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n[{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}][{}]\n'\
        .format(cell_dict[1],cell_dict[2],cell_dict[3],cell_dict[4],cell_dict[5],cell_dict[6],cell_dict[7],cell_dict[8],cell_dict[9],cell_dict[10],\
                cell_dict[11],cell_dict[12],cell_dict[13],cell_dict[14],cell_dict[15],cell_dict[16],cell_dict[17],cell_dict[18],cell_dict[19],cell_dict[20],\
                cell_dict[21],cell_dict[22],cell_dict[23],cell_dict[24],cell_dict[25],cell_dict[26],cell_dict[27],cell_dict[28],cell_dict[29],cell_dict[30],\
                cell_dict[31],cell_dict[32],cell_dict[33],cell_dict[34],cell_dict[35],cell_dict[36],cell_dict[37],cell_dict[38],cell_dict[39],cell_dict[40],\
                cell_dict[41],cell_dict[42],cell_dict[43],cell_dict[44],cell_dict[45],cell_dict[46],cell_dict[47],cell_dict[48],cell_dict[49],cell_dict[50],\
                cell_dict[51],cell_dict[52],cell_dict[55],cell_dict[54],cell_dict[55],cell_dict[56],cell_dict[57],cell_dict[58],cell_dict[59],cell_dict[60],\
                cell_dict[61],cell_dict[62],cell_dict[66],cell_dict[64],cell_dict[65],cell_dict[66],cell_dict[67],cell_dict[68],cell_dict[69],cell_dict[70],\
                cell_dict[71],cell_dict[72],cell_dict[73],cell_dict[74],cell_dict[75],cell_dict[77],cell_dict[77],cell_dict[78],cell_dict[79],cell_dict[80],\
                cell_dict[81],cell_dict[82],cell_dict[83],cell_dict[84],cell_dict[85],cell_dict[86],cell_dict[87],cell_dict[88],cell_dict[89],cell_dict[90],\
                cell_dict[91],cell_dict[92],cell_dict[93],cell_dict[94],cell_dict[95],cell_dict[96],cell_dict[97],cell_dict[98],cell_dict[99],cell_dict[100]))
```

The resulting board looks like the one below, minus the extra space in between, where the cells can be replaced with letters and numbers by changing the Cell class items in cell_dict. Pardon the weird request but thanks in advance!

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `.format(*cell_dict.values())`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hard-coding whole `str` you might use str multiplication by int (result in repeating) and `'\n'.join` to join such created rows, example:

```
size = 3
cell = '[{}]'
row = cell*size
board = '\n'.join([row]*size)
print(board)
```

output

```
[{}][{}][{}]
[{}][{}][{}]
[{}][{}][{}]
```

which might then be used with `.format`:

```
print(board.format(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

output

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

Note that `.join` needs iterable for example list, so I create list with single row and do `* size` to get list holding `size` amount of same elements.